# Javascript change the data in some data

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that's returning the following content:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "refnumber":3,
    "active":false,
    "date":"2017-09-14T23:00:00.000Z",
    "addons":0,
    "age":0
}
```

If you look at the data field I need a way of changing the data on that field to yyyy-mm-dd.

In other words .. if we take this example as a reference I would need the data field value:

This:

```
2017-09-14T23:00:00.000Z
```

To be changed to this:

```
2017-09-14
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to slice away the trailing characters.

```
data.date = data.date.slice(0, 10);
```

This works because your data format is in a predictable form where the month and day have a `0` padding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a library called momentjs for all your javascript date manipulation needs.

https://momentjs.com/

With it, you can do what you want easily: `moment(data.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: no need for moment, if you have an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string and need just to make is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your JSON is invalid because the `date` string is not properly quoted, but assuming it's corrected and that your JSON object is named `myObject`, the following would work:

```
var date = new Date(myObject.date); //your string will become a date object

//now operate on that date object by extracting the year, month,
//and day into a string
console.log(date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could convert the string to date and then format it
Here is an example

```
function formate(date) {
if (typeof date == "string")
    date = new Date(date);
  var day = (date.getDate() <= 9 ? "0" + date.getDate() : 
 date.getDate());
 var month = (date.getMonth() + 1 <= 9 ? "0" + 
(date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1));
var dateString = day + "-" + month + "-" + 
date.getFullYear() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + 
date.getMinutes();

return dateString;
}
```